# Why 2 GB and not 4 GB on 32 bits limitation?

Tags: mongodb

Sorry for this dumb question, but when [reading about 32 bits limitation](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations), i found that due to Memory-Mapped method, MongoDB can't store more than 2 GB, but:

```
2^32 = 4 GB
```

So why the limit is only 2 GB? is that because:

```
2^(32-1) = 2 GB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is due to [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) organization. Part of 4 GB address space is reserved for operating system (kernel space), so only part (user space, usually 2GB or 3GB) is available to the process itself. Memory mapped files must fit into this limitation.

Comment: so the process takes `2^(32-1)`

Comment: If the 32 bit process uses all it's available virtual memory (let it be limited by 2GB) it will use 2GB plus some memory for kernel structures but no more than 4GB alltogather.

Comment: Now i understand, thank you :)
»On a 32-bit Microsoft Windows installation, by default, only 2 GiB are made available to processes for their own use.The other 2GB are used by the operating system.

Comment: so what if the 2 Giga has ben modified to 3 Giga as is done on Windows, does Mongodb follow it?